# Big Sur: Time Machine couldn't complete the backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk, big-sur

I keep getting the following error in Time Machine:

[image: Time_machine_error]

I am backing up my macOS drive (Macintosh HD - Data) to an external drive (EsEsDe), and I'm being told that the backup cannot be completed because my macOS drive is nearly full - there's plenty of space on the backup disk.

Is this expected behaviour? If there's room on the backup disk, why should it matter that the disk I'm trying to backup is nearly full?

Is there a way around this other than the obvious (which isn't really an option for me at the moment)?

Results of diskutil list:[image]

Comment: Can you, extern disk connected, add to your question the result of terminal command : ``diskutil list ``?

Comment: I have now added this.

Comment: Your external disk has a partition scheme fdisk. I'm not sure but on Mac Os X it's better use guid scheme. Don't you have an system update in progress? Because your system volume has 24 g instead of 12 g